# Is a category based directory recommended in URLs?

Tags: seo, url, keywords, url-slug, url-keywords

From an SEO point of view, which of the two options are recommended?

```
www.example.com/cell-phones-reviews/samsung-galaxy/
or
www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-review/
```

I guess the keyword string in this fictional case is "samsung galaxy review" so the second option has an advantage on this, but perhaps not as important as a "nicely structured" URL as the first one.

Note that "cell-phones-reviews" is actually the category. So do I use the first option or do I remove the parent/category slug from the URL and use the second?

I could combine the two and make a third option:

```
www.example.com/cell-phones-reviews-/samsung galaxy-review/
```

but then there would be repeated keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one point directory depth was recommended as a way to advantage keywords, however, today that advice does not hold true. It is believed that the further down in depth you go, the less important the page is. Search engines work on this principle. Having said that, I would recommend some other options with some assumptions.

www.example.com/cell-phones-reviews/samsung-galaxy.html

or

www.example.com/cell-phones-reviews.html
www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-review.html

The assuptions are: I assume that you will have a page that lists/links the various reviews, and that each review has a page.

There is some exception to the depth theory (stated above) that allows one level from the root directory. Going two levels from the root risks losing importance regardless of how it is linked. At one point depth was only measured in links from the root, but now it seems that link and directory depth can count against you as search engines now use these metrics as indicators. Depth is recommended in that a flat site does not take advantage of organization. You see, search engines like balance. Not a flat site, and not too deep. They measure the norm, and anything within the norm is okay. Anything outside, begins to become suspect. It's a metrics game. If the world suddenly shifts to using two levels deep, then my advice would change again.

Please remember that while SEO has taken advantage of a method, there has always been a push back against gaming the system. This often effects the innocent too. That is where we are with depth.

I am not saying you cannot go two levels deep, I am simply not recommending it as an SEO tactic anymore.

If you do not want to expose your web pages, then I suggest:

www.example.com/cell-phones-reviews/
www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-review/

Comment: thank you for your answer. I will try and use your suggestion [www.example.com/cell-phones-reviews/ www.example.com/samsung-galaxy-review/] . This makes me wander if i will have any problems with urls beeing too short. For example some of the urls will be from only two short words. Joost de Valk once suggested that urls should try and be at least 40 characters long, and of course not too big. Will i have any problems with short 1-2 words urls like example.com/make-nice/ ( from an SEO point of view ofc )?

Comment: Sometimes people recommend one thing when in reality there are other factors in play. For example, it may be that the 40 character suggestion has nothing to do with practical text limits such as with a title tag, but has something to do with keyword density and usage. I do not see a problem with 1 or 2 words as a directory name. I can see *samsung galaxy* as being more powerful then *cell phones*. Take all of this in balance with on-page and off-page optimization and you will be okay. If cell phones ends up being weaker, create more in-bound links with *cell phones* in the url/alt text.

Answer (score 1):

> Create a simple directory structure
>
> Use a directory structure that organizes your content well and makes
> it easy for visitors to know where they're at on your site. Try using
> your directory structure to indicate the type of content found at that
> URL.
>
> Avoid:
>
> - Using excessive keywords like "baseball-cards-baseball-cards-baseballcards.htm".

— Says Google.

Source: [Search Engine Optimization (SEO) Starter Guide](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/beginner/seo-starter-guide).